# Filter tags in eclipse git repositories view

Tags: java, eclipse, egit

There are many tags exists under **tags** node present inside the eclipse **Git repositories** view. Is there any way to filter some of these tags and show only few related tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no filtering in the Git Repositories view.

What do you want to do with the tags? Maybe there is a different way to do what you want (not via the Git Repositories view).

Comment: There are many tags exists under tags node, these tags are created by other developers.But I want to see the tags created by me only.Loading all tags in git repository view takes long time and I have to scroll a lot to reach my tags.

Comment: Do these tags use a naming scheme, like "foo/tag-1" and "bar/tag-1"? If yes, [EGit bug 390158](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390158) would help you (not yet implemented).

Comment: Will wait for next EGIT release